# PDF: How can I override/fix searchable text in a scanned image + OCR file?

Tags: pdf, adobe, edit, acrobat

I'm trying to create an index on a PDF file that I scanned as images from an old original manuscript, then put through character recognition in Adobe Acrobat Pro. The problem is some of the words were spaced funny so the OCR ended up with flaws. I used the **find and fix suspects tool** but there are still problems.

Case in point...

The text "**FOR EXAMPLE**" was spaced funny in the original document (and its image of course) so that Adobe reads it as three words "**FOR EX AMPLE**" which then results in an index entry for the word "*ample*" that looks perfectly valid if I did not know better. This is one of several similar problems with the document that I have identified so far (still more pages to proofread).

How can I fix the underlying OCR text so that it contains the correct information *both* in the created index *and* when searching the document.

PS: I cannot just switch to a pure OCR text version of the document since the manuscript is technical and has lots of drawings associated with the text. I need to keep the images and alter the "hidden" searchable text underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/718672/269989) suggesting [ABBYY FineReader 14](https://www.abbyy.com/en-us/finereader/edit-pdf/) (commercial; I am not affiliated).  It looks like it will handle the editing, after which I presume your existing workflow would take care of the indexing.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516851/2877364) is another answer giving some more workflow details (albeit three years ago).

Separately, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/220445/2877364) has answers suggesting Perl's [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF) and [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/).

Comment: I went and watched a number of tutorial videos on **ABBYY FineReader 14** and it certainly does appear that it would solve my problem. I am going to download the trial version to confirm. Unfortunately if it does the job then it means I will have to layout almost $200 more for functionality that Adobe -- [**who invented PDF**](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/about-adobe-pdf.html) -- ought to have already included in their expensive flagship product. Very aggravating to say the least. Anyways thank you for your answer, the bounty is yours.

Comment: @O.M.Y. Thanks very much, and good luck with your work!  Definitely a frustrating situation - I wish you the best.